# VS2019 .editorconfig is not respected

Tags: visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

We're struggling to set a team-standard indent style for javascript/typescript and from all indications, the settings in `.editorconfig` are *not* overriding user preferences as indicated at the bottom of VS when we open the solution

[image]

For testing purposes, I've created the world's simplest `.editorconfig` with a ridiculous indent size value, and added it to the root folder of the solution:

```
# All files
[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 27
```

Then, under Tools | Options | Text Editor | JavaScript/TypeScript | Tabs, I've set a different indent size value:

[image]

So - if `.editorconfig` is really being used, any attempt to reformat a Typescript file should result in 27 spaces of indenting at each level. No dice.

I've tried moving the file to the same folder as the Typescript files I want to format. No dice.

I've verified that "Follow project coding conventions" is selected under Tools | Options | Text Editor | General. I've also turned it off. No dice.

It *always* formats to the indent size specified in Tools | Options.

Is there some magic sauce I'm missing?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/792737/editorconfig-ignored-for-javascript-files.html

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/331791/visual-studio-ignored-editorconfig-after-update-76.html

Comment: Version 16.3.0 was developed with a strict deadline to coincide with the .NETCore v3.0 release and it shows.  It wasn't done.  Keep an eye on the linked bug reports.  Best to stick to a 16.2.x version until it stabilizes a bit.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm having the same problem on VS 2019 v16.9.3... is it still possible? Also, I don't see the status bar message `User preferences overridden by`.

Answer (score -3):

Project proprities
Code Analysis
enable Run On live Analysis opt